# Incorrect alert "An error occurred during voting" when trying to delete comments

Tags: bug, comments, user-interface, deleted-comments

There is a little bug in the site meta.stackoverflow.com.

I encountered the bug several times, here are the steps:

1. I click the cross, to delete my comment posted about 10 or 15 min ago.
2. I receive an alert "An error occurred during voting."

#### Expected:

The error message has to be corrected (what voting? I did not vote).

#### Reproduced:

Safari on iOS 8.2 on an iPad.

Comment: You may not have thought you voted, but you did. That's the way deleting a comment works. Since it is hardly a major problem, I'd guess it'll stay that way.

Comment: The error message is just a bit generic.  The ajax call to delete failed, is all.  If you can repro, get the details from the response and add them to an [edit].

Comment: @Bill The site mechanics modelling it as something it calls a vote does not make it a vote.

Comment: Was this on the now-removed mobile website? Can anyone reproduce this currently?